# regex extract in hadoop with pipe (escape character) as delimiter

Tags: java, regex, string, hadoop

I have a string "Hadoop|regex|Issue". I want to split using | as delimiter. I used this code -
`String[] afterSplit = string.split("\\|");` but afterSplit contains only 2 strings "Hadoop" and "regex". I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception when I try to retrieve afterSplit[2]. I want "Issue" in afterSplit[2].

I also tried the below code

`String regex = Pattern.quote("|");
String[] parts = line.split(regex);`

Note: Both work in simple java code but I get error while trying to implement in Hadoop. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `split("|")` ?

Comment: `split("|")` doesn't work. split() takes regex as parameter and | is an escape character which denotes OR. It should be parsed correctly so `split("\\|)`. It retrieves 'Hadoop' and 'regex' from input string but not able to retrieve 'Issue'